# SQL Server Express With Advanced Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have some tables which contain JSON data and I need to create some report in PDF format from JSON data, I know that Express edition of SQL Server is free but I need to use reporting services as well to generate reports in PDF format, I am wondering if reporting service and express edition is free in "SQL Server Express With Advanced Services" in production environment.
I know the features are limited but it would be a small database (less than 1 GB) with minimal load on it and my only requirement is to generate PDF from JSON data.

Comment: I don't think there are any 'commerical' limitations, just database size, total memory , number of cores etc. Also, I don't think you can access remote databases from the SSRS instance but that should not be a problem for you as it sounds like you are going to use SQL Server Express for the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JSON parser with a windows based application to parse the data and load it into a database. Then use a reporting tool: Crystal Reports, SSRS to extract out the data. This data can be exported from those tools to a PDF format.